# Partial derivatives where implicit equations are involved

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule, implicit-differentiation

I have a function:
$$f\bigl(P,R\bigr)=h\bigl(P,R,N(P,R)\bigr)$$
where $P$ and $R$ are independent variables and $N$ is the solution of the equation:
$$P-g(R,N)=0$$
I am trying to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N(P,R)$ is not an independent variable, rather a function (of $P$ and $R$).  Hence partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $P$ and $R$ exist.

The solution is to obtain $\frac{\partial g}{\partial R}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}$ from the solution of $P-g(R,N)=0$.

At the solution, P = g, and hence:
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial P}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}}$$
$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial R}=-\frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial R}}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}}$$
Use these derivatives with the chain rule in the evaluation of
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial P}f\bigl(P,R\bigr)$$and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial R}f\bigl(P,R\bigr)$$

Answer (score 3):

To obtain $\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}$, we compute $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}(P,R) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial P}(P,R,N(P,R)) + \frac{\partial h}{\partial N}(P,R,N(P,R))\cdot \frac{\partial N}{\partial P}(P,R).\tag{1}$$ Now, to compute $\frac{\partial N}{\partial P}$ we use the chain rule and the equation $P-g(R,N)=0$.  Differentiating with respect to $P$: $$1  - \frac{\partial g}{\partial N}(R,N)\cdot \frac{\partial N}{\partial P}(P,R) = 0.$$  This gives us $$1 = \frac{\partial g}{\partial N}(R,N)\cdot \frac{\partial N}{\partial P}(P,R) \implies \frac{\partial N}{\partial P}(P,R) = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}(R,N)}.$$  In all, then, by $(1)$ we get $$\boxed{\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}(P,R) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial P}(P,R,N(P,R)) + \frac{\frac{\partial h}{\partial N}(P,R,N(P,R))}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}(R,N)}.}$$

For the second part, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}$, we compute $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}(P,R) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial R}(P,R,N(P,R)) + \frac{\partial h}{\partial N}(P,R,N(P,R))\cdot \frac{\partial N}{\partial R}(P,R).\tag{2}$$  Now, as before, we differentiate $P-g(R,N)=0$ with respect to $R$ to obtain $\frac{\partial N}{\partial R}$: $$-\frac{\partial g}{\partial R}(R,N) - \frac{\partial g}{\partial N}(R,N)\cdot \frac{\partial N}{\partial R}(P,R) = 0 \implies \frac{\partial N}{\partial R}(P,R) = -\frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial R}(R,N)}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}(R,N)}.$$  In all, then, by $(2)$ we get $$\boxed{\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}(P,R) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial R}(P,R,N(P,R)) - \frac{\partial h}{\partial N}(P,R,N(P,R))\cdot \frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial R}(R,N)}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}(R,N)}.}$$

Comment: I do need the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $P$ and $R$.  Perhaps I have not formulated it correctly.  It is really a function of $P$ and $R$ only, I guess $N$ can be considered an internal variable within the calculation of $f$.

Comment: I thought I had to take $N$ and its derivatives into consideration as the partials I get are not the same as a numerical perturbation of $R$ and $P$ on $f$.  So I'm still in the dark.

Comment: I got the analytical and numerical derivatives to be the same.  It turns out that the derivatives of $N$ are required in the calculation of the derivatives of $f$. As $N$ is a function of $P$ and $R$, then from the equation for $N$: $P-g(R,N)=0$, I obtained $\frac{\partial N}{\partial P}$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial R}$ and used these in the calculation of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial P}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial R}$.

Comment: Got it.  In that case, I would have restated the problem as $f(P,R) = h(P,R,N(P,R))$, so that it is clear that the function you need to differentiate only depends on $P$ and $R$, but it is expressed in such a way that $P$ and $R$ are also tied up in the calculation of $N$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I updated the function definition, and provided my solution below.

Comment: Ok, notice that your solution is the same as mine for calculating $\frac{\partial N}{\partial P}$

Comment: Almost - mine has $\frac{\partial g}{\partial N}$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ack.  That was a typo, thanks for catching that.  Also, I've updated my answer to reflect the new notation.